# Solve $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx} + h(x,t)$ using Fourier transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Consider the problem:

$$ \begin{cases}
u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx} + h(x,t), \hspace{0.5cm} x \in \mathbb{R}, \hspace{0.3cm} t>0\\
u(x,0) = f(x), \hspace{0.5cm} x \in \mathbb{R}\\
u_{t}(x,0) = g(x) \hspace{0.5cm} x \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to use Fourier transform to formally find a solution to this problem. I solved the homogeneous case in which $h(x,t) = 0$, then I wanted to proceed analogously with this case, but the problem leads me to a nonhomogeneous second-order ordinary differential equation. This is:

Applying Fourier transform on the variable $x$, the following is obtained:

$$\mathcal{F}\{ \partial_{tt}(x,t)\} = c^2 \mathcal{F}\{\partial_{xx}u(x,t)\} + \mathcal{F}\{h(x,t)\} \Rightarrow \partial_{tt}\hat{u} = -c^2 \omega\hat{u} + \hat{h}(\omega,t)$$

How can I continue with this?
Or is my way of doing this wrong and there is a better way to do it instead?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You are not doing this wrong. You now just have to solve the ODE in $\hat{u}$. Another way to do it is to use [D'Alemberts formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula), your result using the FT should match this result.

Comment: @mattos Thank you so  much, but how can I solve the ODE in $\hat{u}$ with unknown $\hat{h}$? I was trying to use Duhamel's formula.